# In typescript I don't understand why i getting the error 'Service1 | Service2 | null' is not assignable to type '(Service1 & Service2) | null'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a "baby" IoC container for an easy personal app. What I'm trying to achieve with this code is to have a defined type for the param `service` in the method `registerService` based on the key passed as first param

but i'm getting the error

```
Type 'Service1 | Service2 | null' is not assignable to type '(Service1 & Service2) | null'.
  Type 'Service1' is not assignable to type 'Service1 & Service2'.
    Property 'thing2' is missing in type 'Service1' but required in type 'Service2'.
```

My code:

```js
export const SERVICE_ONE_KEY = 'service1'
export const SERVICE_TWO_KEY = 'service2'

type Service1 = {
  thing1: () => void
}

type Service2 = {
  thing2: () => void
}

type IocKeys = typeof SERVICE_ONE_KEY | typeof SERVICE_TWO_KEY
type Services = {
  [SERVICE_ONE_KEY]: Service1 | null
  [SERVICE_TWO_KEY]: Service2 | null
}

const registry: Services = {
  service1: null,
  service2: null
}

export const registerService = (name: IocKeys, service: Services[typeof name]): Services[typeof name] => {
  registry[name] = service // Error here
  return registry[name]
}

export const getService = (name: IocKeys): Services[typeof name] => {
    return registry[name]
}
```

Is possible to try a "working" example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMoFEBKA1ASQGEsB9AeQDkyBpLATTgF44ByVYKANwEsFgAjKwCwAKFCRYiFOjjZ8xMgBUA6uVJ1GLdp178ATCNFiYATzDA5uvoOZwA3mLhwYACx7IA5gIBccABQAlMwAfHBcEDwAJmIAvmIm5pYY1gZ2jqLObh6e+n5BoeGRMaLxxqJmFnAEEAg0wKaodpXAEABmcriEJBTUGgxwAD4uSe2dCj2q6pqJVSncNk0sGc4A2vLdZFS0DAC6fvN6tsPIAK4ANudOcOtdiqRT-fT7VgtpJxdXpQmiSGjwUGAnh46CgpgOqWASwc1w4b0EfjOlwANLDIXk4EivmUxBJoPA-rJAcD0JxDjY7P5kABDAC2wD8NTqDVQyLgcKOEPhqFWLTGNPpu0CXKOPL5HQFwF2hRWcGJIJgYNWkulLA5NmugJgpygyDlQIVSpVcR+eKkhPgnmAMHJ-EpksZtXqjWFr1FvNGErpUplYgAkFqdXr5aDTMrvbsTaIgA) to understand whats wrong!

UPDATE 1

I would also like to have a defined return type based on the name param key in the `getService` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achived using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
export const registerService = <T extends IocKeys>(name: T, service: Services[T]): Services[T] => {
  registry[name] = service
  return registry[name]
}

export const getService = <T extends IocKeys>(name: T): Services[T] => {
  return registry[name]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wMoFEBKA1ASQGEsB9AeQDkyBpLATTgF44ByVYKANwEsFgAjKwCwAKFCRYiFOjjZ8xMgBUA6uVJ1GLdp178ATCNFiYATzDA5uvoOZwA3mLhwYACx7IA5gIBccABQAlMwAfHBcEDwAJmIAvmIm5pYY1gZ2jqLObh6e%20n5BoeGRMaLxxqJmFnAEEAg0wKaodpXAEABmcriEJBTUGgxwAD4uSe2dCj2q6pqJVSncNk0sGc4A2vLdZFS0DAC6fvN6tsPIAK4ANudOcOtdiqRT-fT7VgtpJxdXpQmiSGjwUGAnh46CgpgOqWASwc1w4b0EfjOlwANLDIXk4EivmUxBJoPA-rJAcD0JxDjY7AAeJRwUAwYDIKJNGp1BqoEL%20ZAAQwAtsA-EpkXA4UcIfDUKslLtAmKjhKpYUVnBiSCYGDVty%20bs7CKbNdATBTlBkMqgar1ZrgLs4j88VJCfBPMAYOT%20FSaXSGUzqrV6o0OZaBTLXnLJdqmGElQajSaVaDTBreVabeUHXA2hAIHYnS7If4dPChMEAPTFkM2ARDTGfIA)

Comment: Awesome mate! Thank you very much! Sometimes I got confused by typescript typing system 